# bash sem - limit number of sem commands based on id

Tags: bash, semaphore, gnu-parallel

I have a scenario in my script where I am running few `sem` commands simultaneously. Here i am running 1000 sem commands simultaneously.

filename: `sem_script.sh`

```
#/usr/bin/bash
fun() {
  #dosomething with the $param
  echo $1
}
export -f fun

sem --id someid --fg fun $param
```

The reason i am using `sem` is i want `fun` to run one after another

so if i do

```
sh sem_script.sh "test" &
sh sem_script.sh "test" &
sh sem_script.sh "test" &
sh sem_script.sh "test" &
sh sem_script.sh "test" &
sh sem_script.sh "test" &
...
..
... more than 1000 times
sh sem_script.sh "test" &
sh sem_script.sh "test" &
sh sem_script.sh "test" &
```

then it will output

```
test
test
test
test
test
test
...
..
... more than 1000 times
test
test
test
```

But problem here it opens 1000 sem commands at a time and they are waiting in queue to run one after another. This chokes up my cpu and my ram and everything jams.

So i decided that I dont want to allow more than 4 sem commands to be in queue for a particular `id` here `someid`

What is want is as below:

```
#/usr/bin/bash
fun() {
  #dosomething with the $param
  echo $1
}
export -f fun

num_sem_instances = get how many sem instances are running with id someid
if(num_sem_instances < 4), then {
  #allow to create a sem instance 
  sem --id someid --fg fun $param
}
else {
  #dont create an sem instance
  echo "already have 4 instances of sem with id=someid"
  # rerun the script again and try your luck
  sh sem_script.sh "test" &
}
```

Because in bash when scripts execute simultenously the above logic may not work. It will work when there is some time delay in scripts

Better than the above logic i strongly prefer that is there an option in `sem` command which will only allow it to have `4` instances of an `id someid` running at any point of time on my pc and rest it will not allow to run.

Comment: You might want to investigate [GNU parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnu-parallel/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a sem is running, it adds a pidfile to ~/.parallel/semaphones/id-someid/, so you should be able to count files here that have pids.

i just ran `sem --id someid -j2 sleep 10` twice in cli and listed out the contents of that directory:

```
[user@laptop ~]$ ls -lah .parallel/semaphores/id-someid/
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user user 4.0K Jul  9 09:47 .
drwxrwxr-x. 3 user user 4.0K Jul  9 09:47 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 3 user user    0 Jul  9 09:47 19428@laptop.wks
-rw-rw-r--. 3 user user    0 Jul  9 09:47 19449@laptop.wks
-rw-rw-r--. 3 user user    0 Jul  9 09:47 id-someid
```

so in your script, i would put

```
num_sem_instances = $(find ~/.parallel/semaphores/id-${YOURID}/ -type f 2> /dev/null | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | grep ^[0-9] | wc -l)
```

**EDIT:**

If only one `sem` can run at a time (i.e. `-j1`), and only four instances of the command can be queued at once, the sem could be wrapped in another parallel process, which queues up the task only after counting the queued commands:

```
fun () { echo $1; sleep 1 }

runfun () {
  numqueued=$(find ~/.parallel/semaphores/id-queued/ -type f 2> /dev/null | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | grep ^[0-9] | wc -l)
  if [ $numqueued < 4 ]; then
    parallel -j4 --bg --id queued sem --id funid --fg fun $1
  else
    echo "too much fun right now"
  fi
}

export -f fun

runfun $1
```

Comment: I will check it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry it took time to check this. I am not running parallel commands. `-j2` will run parallel jobs

Comment: i see; you need to only have one sem run at a time, and have up to 4 queued to run? i'll modify my answer to include something for that

Comment: I will check this. Also can you explain `parallel -j4 --bg --id queued sem --id funid --fg fun $1`. you are using two ids and also `-j4` (to allow four run parallel) and both `--bg and --fg`

Comment: Everything before the `sem` part is for the parallel process, everything after is for the nested sem process. `--bg` will let the script exit after parallel queues the `sem` command. `-j4` is there to override the default `-j1`. The `--fg` for sem is so that `fun()` can output to the terminal. Both processes need different ids so we can keep the job numbers right (one for sem and four for parallel).

Comment: Basically what's happening is that parallels trying to run 4 instances of the fun command at once, but sem restricts it to just 1 at a time. Once the fun finishes and sem exists, the funid semaphore is cleared, and the next parallel is able to run. Running the command wrapped in the test will exit nicely if there are more than 4 runs already, rather than let parallel hang until it can queue (bg) the 5th job.

Comment: I will try it  and check it.

Comment: in my os (archlinux) `~/.parallel/semaphones/id-someid/ ` is not found. I only find the folder `.parallel/semaphores/id-2fdev2fpts2f1`

Comment: The folder only appears when the ID is running; I'm not sure if it's masked or filtered on arch :/ barring that, since `fun` was exported as a function, you might be able to grep for it in a `ps`

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that this is because you need to add a delay between each execution.  The operating system needs to be able to run a command, then allocate some CPU time to another user or process, and then come back and run your next command.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

count=1

next() {
[[ "${count}" -lt 1000 ]] && main
exit 0
}

main() {
sem_script.sh "test"
sleep 0.5
count=$(($count+1))
next
}

next
```

This is very quick and dirty, but it should work.  It creates a counter which goes up to 1,000, and runs the script with a 0.5 second delay, just before each time it increments the counter.  Once the counter is at 1,000, the script exits.

Comment: Even in this there is chance two scripts will run at the same time. When we run multiple times same script from different places we dont know whether they will be running at same time  or with some delay

Comment: I apologise.  I realised this didn't solve your problem after I submitted it.